# elm-bootstrap with elm-css don't get along well?

Tags: elm

I'm trying to use both [elm-css](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/rtfeldman/elm-css/14.0.0) and [elm-bootstrap](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/rundis/elm-bootstrap/4.1.0) in the same project but it looks like they don't get along well.

What I like about elm-css is that it's a drop-in replacement for the html core modules, and by just using other imports and composing your main view with `toUnstyled`, you get all the goodies.

```
{ view = view >> toUnstyled, ... }
```

But elm-bootstrap functions don't expect to receive the elm-css styled elements so we must remove the styles, cluttering my code with calls to `toUnstyled` everywhere, like i.e.

```
Table.td [] [ toUnstyled <| text "Hi!" ]
```

I could live with that, but the real show stopper appears when we need to add attributes like i.e.

```
  Table.td [ Table.cellAttr <| class "text-center" ] 
      [ toUnstyled <| text "Hi!" ]
```

This only works if `class` is from core Html module, not elm-css. It would work if we could use `toUnstyled <| class "text-center`, but this function (for attributes) is "missing" in elm-css (the quotes are there because I'm not sure if it even makes sense to have it, `fromUnstyled` exists though).

So, is `toUnstyled` for attributes really missing?, are there any other viable options for having what both libs offer?

In terms of options, what should be done to elm-bootstrap to make it accept elm-css styled attributes? should it be a wrapper lib that calls to `toUnstyled` before each call to elm-bootstrap? Any thoughts?

Comment: I received no comments so in the end I decided to fork elm-bootstrap and replace imports for module Html with Html.Styled. http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/frandibar/elm-bootstrap/latest. Now I've got a new maintenance problem...